# Use LINQ to find value inside a nested collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following snippet of code that I'd like to convert to LINQ. The goal is to find a match in the inner collection and return its Data property. Any suggestions?

```
    string data = null;
    foreach (var section in sections)
    {
        foreach (var field in section.Fields)
        {
            if (field.Id == id)
            {
                data = field.Data;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Select`, `SelectMany` and `FirstOrDefault()` (or in your case, `LastOrDefault`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.110).aspx) to flatten the collection then flter it with a `Where`

```
var matches = sections
    .SelectMany(s => s.Fields)
    .Where(f => f.Id == id)
    .Select(f => f.Data);
```

Now `matches` contains all the data strings that match. If you only have a single match, you can use `Single` (or `SingleOrDefault` if there may not be any) to get that individual value. If you might have more matches, use `FirstOrDefault` or `LastOrDefault`. (in your code, `Last` is the method that will give you the same answer)

You could put all that together and simplify:

```
data = sections
    .SelectMany(s => s.Fields)
    .SingleOrDefault(f => f.Id == id)
    ?.Data;
```

Note the `?` just in case you have no matches.

Answer (score 0):

The following code would work, based on Rob's comment:

```
sections.SelectMany(x => x.Fields).Where(field => field.Id == id).Select(field => field.Data).FirstOrDefault()
```